# Unable to fix homebrew install on mac

Tags: macos, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I've been trying on and off for the last couple of months to install homebrew on my mac and it is not working. I've tried deleting directories, installing and reinstalling homebrew and then not being able to install certain libraries like mongoosedb, I even reset my computer and the problem is still there.
This is the error message i recieve now when trying to reinstall homebrew.

```
==> Tapping homebrew/core
remote: Enumerating objects: 973663, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (340/340), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (189/189), done.
error: 4292 bytes of body are still expected.67 MiB | 6.00 MiB/s
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
Failed during: git fetch --force origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Any suggestions as too how I could fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: Does it work if you run `git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core /opt/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core --depth=1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stupid as it sounds, the problem was I had Child Block enabled on my virgin wifi.

Comment: this ultimately worked for me, tried running Homebrew installation using Personal hotspot, strangely worked !

Comment: Wish I saw this a few hours ago!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a few ways, since home brew depends on cellar

Try doing

```
rm -f /usr/local/Cellar 

rm -f /usr/local/.git
```

This will reset your git, but the moment you input a clone command, you can proceed after providing git credentials.

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

```
mkdir homebrew && curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew
```

If your have ruby setup

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```