# Unable to install Homebrew on BigSur "Login denied"

Tags: homebrew, macos-big-sur

I am trying to install homebrew on MacOS BigSur, using the command foudn on the homebrew web page:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

But when I do I get this error message, which I suspect has something to so with performing an unshallow clone of the repo.  I don't really know how to get past it though.

```
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/': Login denied
Failed during: git fetch --force origin
```

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/68049634/7275579 ?

Comment: I have the same "Login denied" error when trying to clone a repo on my Mac. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Yes I did in the end, but it won't be very helpful I'm afraid, I re-installed BigSur from scratch which I couldn't recommend as a solution (but it worked).